# Error al llamar libreria de jquery Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Datatable is not a function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema al momento de usar un plugin de datatable, creo que me carga dos veces el script de jquery, pero no sé de donde.

```
<script src="../src/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/getorgchart.js"></script>


<script src="../dist/js/jquery.orgchart.js"></script>
<script src="../src/js/go.js"></script>
<script src="../src/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
<script src="../src/js/jsplumb.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- NProgress -->
<script src="../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
<!-- Chart.js -->
<script src="../vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!-- gauge.js -->
<script src="../vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="../vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<!-- Skycons -->
<script src="../vendors/skycons/skycons.js"></script>
<!-- Flot -->
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
<!-- Flot plugins -->
<script src="../vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js"></script>
<!-- DateJS -->
<script src="../vendors/DateJS/build/date.js"></script>
<!-- JQVMap -->
<script src="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
<script src="../vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<!-- Datatables -->
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons-bs/js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-fixedheader/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-keytable/js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-responsive-bs/js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/datatables.net-scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
```

Codigo de js de mi funcion donde uso el Datatable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                   $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('#datatable').Datatable({
                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                         'Excel', 'PDF', 'print'
                      ]
                      });
                    });
                    function FunSumT(fila,criterio,nfila){
                      var datos=JSON.stringify(criterio);
                      // console.log(datos);
                      // var p=JSON.parse(criterio);
                      var total=0;
                      // var acum=document.getElementById('total0').textContent;
                      // var suma=document.getElementById(idCriterio);
                      var fila=".fila"+nfila+" td";
                      // console.log(fila);
                      var tam=$(fila).length;
                      var peso=[];
                      var i=0;                       
                      $.each(criterio,function(){
                        peso[i]=criterio[i][0];
                        // console.log(peso[i]);
                        i++;
                      });

                      var j=0;
                      i=0;

                      $(fila).each(function(i){
                        if(i>0 && i<tam-1){
                          // $(this).$("select").text()
                          // console.log(peso[j]);
                          total+= parseInt($(this).find("select option:selected").html())*parseInt(peso[j]);
                           j++;

                        }
                      });
                      SumaTotal(total,nfila);
                    }

                    function SumaTotal(total,nfila){
                      var Ftotal="#total"+nfila+"";
                      var sumtotal=total;
                      // console.log(sumtotal);
                      $(Ftotal).html(sumtotal);
                    }

                </script>
```

Error por consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa el nombre de la función:

`$('#datatable').Datatable({` cámbialo por: `$('#datatable').DataTable({` con la segunda T en mayúsculas.

Si aún así no funciona, asegúrate de hacer el import de DataTable correctamente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sí, eso era, ahora si me compila pero me sale un mensaje de alerta del localhost diciendo: DataTables warning: table id=datatable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, al parecer el id de mi tabla era el mismo al que llamaba dateTable y quizas eso me entro en conflicto, le cambie por otro y si funciono. Cabe resaltar que ese error que me salia era por que estaba llamando dos veces a dataTable.